# Alternate between of operational systems i have on dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I have done dual-boot on my laptop with windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, but now i don't know how to access my windows 10. I reboot the laptop but i don't receive the option to choose which operational system i wanna initialize.

How do I alternate the operational system?

[image: the bios picture]

Comment: If you know how to access your BIOS/UEFI, could post a picture of the settings in the `Boot` option?

Comment: updated , do you know how to fix?

Comment: What does it show if you change `Boot mode` to UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that if you cannot boot to Windows, you can boot to Ubuntu.  Start a terminal window (Windows+T on my Xubuntu, not sure on Ubuntu) and enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt install gdisk
df -h
gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

The first command installs gdisk (or does nothing if it is already installed).  The second one shows free disk space, and is a simple way to identify the boot disk, usually the one which holds a partition is mounted on /.  In the above example, the / partition was /dev/sdaN (with N being the partition number).  Once we know the disk, the last command shows how it is partitioned.  Check that it says **Found valid GPT with hybrid MBT**.  If it does not, stop here and report.

If the disk is indeed GPT partitioned (the default nowadays for both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04), the next steps are

```
sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64
sudo os-prober
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Again, the first command is just to make sure that the boot loader is installed.  The second command should find Windows and tell you about it.  If its output is empty, something is wrong with the Windows partition and you probably need to reinstall Windows.  If os-prober tells you that it found Windows, the next command edits the bootloader options.  Add or edit the following lines in **/etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

The first line tells Grub2 to boot into the saved O/S choice, and the second line tells it to save the choice before booting.  The third line tells it to show the choice of O/S and the last line gives the user 10 seconds to make the choice before booting in the previously saved choice.

After editing, execute the last command, that will update the bootloader, and reboot.

First, reboot into UEFI BIOS and change the boot mode from legacy to UEFI(only).  Then see if it works.  If it does not, report back with the output of the previous commands.

Good luck!